# Error when Saving and writing text files while program is in jar

Tags: java, io, minecraft

Hello I am making a addon for bukkit a minecraft server modding program. This program requires me to put a jar into a foulder with an addon text document to provide class locations anyway. Then it uses my class and cast it into the class into the a class  that it requires my class to inherit from. I am trying to write a text file in the same directory as my program so i wrote this(it is for a money program) (playerName is a pramater i used it as the filename because it is the player you are keeping balance for)

```
try{
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(new File(".").getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+playerName + ".txt",true);
    getLogger().log(Level.INFO,"trying to save text document to " + new File("").getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+playerName + ".tct");
    writer = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    writer.write("30");
    return 30;
}
catch(Exception err){
     getLogger().log(Level.INFO, "Exception occoured!{0}", err.getMessage());
     return -1;
}
```

when i try to read it with this code it throws an exception

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(".").getAbsolutePath()+"/"+playerName));
Integer i = Integer.getInteger(reader.readLine());
return i.intValue();
```

Also i cannot find the text document it suposedly wrote. Any advice?
Also i would like to try to save it back a file so it is not saved in the .jar file but i dont know how to do that.
Also is there a possibility it is saving the file in the folder that the program that is using the class?  Thanks XD

Comment: What exception? What's the directory?

Comment: "/" is almost certainly, but not necessarily, a safe thing to use to separate path components. Use File.separator instead.

Comment: *"..while program is in jar"*  A resource in a Jar is not a `File` and cannot be treated as one.  Further, resources in Jars can be read, but (typically) not written.

Answer (score 0):

That’s the strangest thing I’ve seen for long:

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(new File(".").getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+playerName + ".txt",true);
getLogger().log(Level.INFO,"trying to save text document to " + new File("").getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+playerName + ".tct");
```

Try to clean up:

```
File f=new File(playerName + ".txt");
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(f, true);
getLogger().log(Level.INFO,"trying to save text document to " + f.getAbsolutePath());
```

Next thing: you should always close files after working with then.

Then your file names do not match. One time it is `playername+".txt"` the next time it is just `playername`

But the biggest mistake:

```
Integer i = Integer.getInteger(reader.readLine());
return i.intValue();
```

`Integer.getInteger` does *not* parse the string. It will look for a system property of that name (you won’t have a system property named `"30"`) and interpret this as integer if it exists. In your case it will return `null` thus you get a `NullPointerException` when calling `intValue` on it. Use `Integer.parseInt` instead:

```
try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(playerName+".txt"))) {
  Integer i = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
  return i.intValue();
}
```